# UIProgressView+AFNetworking not updating progress

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2, uiprogressview

I am trying to use the category UIProgressView+AFNetworking from AFNetworking UIKit.
I have an operation that uploads photos to a server. Mulitple photos at once. But my progress view isn't updating at all.

In my UIProgressView I use

```
[progressView setProgressWithUploadProgressOfOperation:operation animated:YES];
```

And my request is:

```
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation =
        [manager POST:url parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
            [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"imageFile" fileName:fileName mimeType:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image/%@",fileMime]];
            NSLog(@"Uploading...");
            [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Uploading File..."];

        } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            //Success

        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            //Fail
            [manager.operationQueue cancelAllOperations];

        }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead){
        double progress = (double)totalBytesRead / totalBytesExpectedToRead;
        NSLog(@"Progress: %.2f", progress);
        // ...
    }];
```

I have my own progress bar, so I change its value in the `setDownloadProgressBlock` block.